# Confusion about Concavity

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis

Simple question.

The function g of a single variable is defined by g(x) =  f(ax + b), where  f  is a concave function of a single variable that is not necessarily differentiable, and a and b are constants with a ≠ 0. (These constants may be positive or negative.) Either show that the function g is concave, or show that it is not necessarily concave. [Your argument must apply to the case in which  f  is is not necessarily differentiable.]

I know that the condition for concavity is:

g((1-α)x1 + αx2) ≥ (1-α)g(x1) + αg(x2) for all x1 and x2 where x1 < x2, and α ∈ [0,1]

Because g(x) =  f(ax + b)
g((1-α)x1 + αx2) = f(a((1-α)x1 + αx2) + b) 
g((1-α)x1 + αx2) = f((1-α)(ax1+b) + α(ax2+b))
g((1-α)x1 + αx2) ≥ αf(ax2 + b) + (1−α)f(ax1 + b)
                   (by the concavity of  f )
                 = αg(x2) + (1 − α)g(x1).

Why is f((1-α)(ax1+b) + α(ax2+b)) ≥ αf(ax1 + b) + (1−α)f(ax2 + b) the condition for concavity of f(ax+b)?
I thought that at x = (1-α)x1 + αx2, the value of f(ax+b) = f(a((1-α)x1 + αx2) + b) and therefore this value must be greater than the corresponding value on the line connecting the endpoints x1 and x2, which is αf(x2) + (1−α)f(x1), or αf(ax2 + b) + (1−α)f(ax1 + b).
Why is it necessary to show that f((1-α)(ax1+b) + α(ax2+b))?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Sincerely,
OMAX

Answer (score 0):

$$g(αx_1 + (1−α)x_2) =  f (a(αx_1 + (1−α)x_2) + b)
=  f (α(ax_1 + b) + (1−α)(ax_2 + b))
≥ α f (ax_1 + b) + (1−α) f (ax_2 + b)
(\text{by the concavity of}  f )
= αg(x_1) + (1 − α)g(x_2)$$.

Comment: Thank you, John.  I understand this is the proof.  What was confusing me is that f(α(ax1+b)+(1−α)(ax2+b))≥ αf(ax1+b)+(1−α)f(ax2+b) is the condition for concavity, and that f(a(αx1+(1−α)x2)+b)≥ αf(ax1+b)+(1−α)f(ax2+b) is not sufficient. I thought the value of the function f(z) at the point z = αx1+(1−α)x2 must be greater than the value of the line connecting x1 and x2 at the point z = αx1+(1−α)x2.What your proof indicates is that for f(z) = f(aj+b) and j = αj1+(1−α)j2, f(a(j)+b) is not the term to compare to j = αj1+(1−α)j2 for proving concavity or convexity, but rather f(αz(j1)+(1−α)z(j2)) is.